# Binding to NSAttributedString

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to bind to NSAttributedString instead of the value in an NSTextField? I have some colorized text (in my ViewModel) that I would like to show up instead of monkeying with the view.

Comment: Monkeying with which view?  You're aware that NSTextView does have an attributedString binding?

Comment: have you tried Font Color binding in NSTextField?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a *Value Transformer* from `NSString` to `NSAttributedString`. But this works only with NSTextField's *Value* binding, not with *Value With Pattern* binding.